# Hibernate could not determine type of MappedSuperClass field

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

### Problem

I have a Field in a MappedSuperClass which is anotated with @Column but the type of the field is not being determined by Hibernate.

**Classes**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperClass
public abstract class IdentifiableObject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperClass
public abstract class EvaluationPeriodObject extends IdentifiableObject{
    @Column
    private Period period;
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERIOD")
public class Period extends IdentifiableObject {
    @Column
    private LocalDate start;
    @Column
    private LocalDate end;
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = MY_CLASS, indexes = {
    @Index(name = "FK_MY_CLASS_PERIOD", columnList = "PERIOD")
})
public class MyClass extends EvaluationPeriodObject {
    @Column
    private String description;
}
```

### Stacktrace

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: Period, at table: MY_CLASS, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(period)]
at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:455)
at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:422)
at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:226)
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:597)
at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:459)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879)
... 45 more
```

### Additional Info

Hibernate Version: `compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.13.Final'`

SpringBoot Version `2.0.0.RELEASE`

> If more Information is required, let me know.
>
> I've been reading most post about this but form what I've read they mostly envolve people using annotations on 'Getters' and 'Fields', Since I'm using Lombok I don't have any Getters to put the annotations on so I believe this is not the problem I'm facing.

Comment: I would imagine persisting a period would require at least two columns?

Comment: @Paul Janssens Period is its own table in the DB, so I don't think I need multiple columns

Comment: @NodonDarkeye Hey, did you solve the issue somehow? I am struggling it too...

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add AccessType.FIELD to getter and setter annotations `@Getter(AccessType.FIELD)`.

Comment: There is no such option for `@Getter`